# Unzip_file causing Media file upload error

Tags: php, functions, wp-filesystem

When I attempt to use the [unzip_file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unzip_file) function below in my `functions.php`:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
WP_Filesystem();
$destination = wp_upload_dir();
$destination_path = $destination['path'];
$unzipfile = unzip_file( $destination_path.'/filename.zip', $destination_path);

if ( is_wp_error( $unzipfile ) ) {
    echo 'There was an error unzipping the file.'; 
} else {
    echo 'Successfully unzipped the file!';       
}
```

I get the following error when trying to upload any files into the Media library in **Media** > **Add New**:

```
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

I am using Twenty Nineteen theme with no plugins activated. I don't get the error when I remove the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly do you "use" it? What's the actual code in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: It's being used and included in `functions.php` exactly as above. There is a `filename.zip` file in my uploads folder, which gets unzipped into the same folder as it should. The only problem is uploading media files while this function is in place.

Comment: You should run the code only when necessary and from the right "place". Did you put it inside a function? And did you hook it to an action like `init`? E.g. `add_action( 'init', function(){ if ( expression ) { // run your code } } );`

Comment: Yes, I already tried it inside a function on init with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work without errors by using it inside `add_attachment` hook below, but now the problem is it runs on every media upload.

```
function unzip_icon_fonts( $post_ID ){
    $file_path = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    WP_Filesystem();
    $destination = wp_upload_dir();
    $destination_path = $destination['path'];
    $unzipfile = unzip_file($file_path, $destination_path); 
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'unzip_icon_fonts' );
```

I tried restricting it to a specific Customizer file upload below, but then it doesn't work at all.

```
function unzip_icon_fonts( $post_ID ){
    // If attachment ID equals Customizer file upload ID added with WP_Customize_Media_Control
    if ( $post_ID == get_theme_mod('icon_fonts', '') ) {
        $file_path = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        WP_Filesystem();
        $destination = wp_upload_dir();
        $destination_path = $destination['path'];
        $unzipfile = unzip_file($file_path, $destination_path); 
    }
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'unzip_icon_fonts' );
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little old, but after you get_attached_file, you can check the path for the extension (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```php
<?php

$file_path = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);

// do nothing if not zip
if ( path_parts['extension'] !== 'zip' ) {
   return;
}
     
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
WP_Filesystem();
$destination = wp_upload_dir();
$destination_path = $destination['path'];
$unzipfile = unzip_file($file_path, $destination_path);
```